# How to call a method on other class in other folder using the .getName() method

Tags: java, file, methods, type-conversion

As my title implies, I was finding a way on how to call a method from other class from another folder using the `.getName()` method which returns `String` value.

I came across reflection which I can't really understand and if it would work with this.

My first file has the method to be called and was located at `.\JBP` *(\Java\JBP)*

```
public class jbp18 {
  public void desc() {
    print("Binary addition");
  }
}
```

Where as my main program located at . (\Java) contains this:

```
print(""+file.getName().replace(".class","")+" - ");
print(file.getName().replace(".class","").desc()); //SHOULD BE jbp18.desc()
```

Are there any much simpler codes than reflection method that I can understand and use to make the `print(jbp18.desc())`?

I have around 20 files that needs to be like this and I was basing on their positions so I can't just call them all so I wanted to use loop to get all their descriptions using the `jbp#.desc()` method.

Comment: You may want to rethink you design...

Comment: I am sorry, but this solution sounds horrible

Comment: isn't that `desc` static? can be a pain to create an instance for each class...

Comment: @assylias I'll do that right now, thanks, might as well try the first answer that was given.

Answer (score 1):

You can call a method in this way:

Let's say we have this class and this method

```
public class YourClass{
    public void printString(String myString){
        System.out.println(myString);
    }
}
```

1) First of all get your method, in this example the method has a String parameter:

```
Method yourMethod = YourClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("printString", String.class);
```

Then, you can call it with:

```
YourClass entity = new YourClass();
yourMethod.invoke(entity, "test123");
```

Comment: `null` check is not used, a `NoSuchMethodException` will be thrown by `getDeclaredMethod`

Comment: done edits as your suggestions: btw the check != null is useful imho, because I wanna check if the method has been found. If I search for a wrong method it will returns null

Comment: `yourMethod` will never be `null`, so it is in fact useless

Comment: Note: you may use `Class.forName(String)` to get a class if its name is in a String (without knowing it at compile time)

Comment: yep, I've tried to keep that general so you can reuse the method easier

Comment: its just a bit confusing - if I had `yourEntity`, I could just call the method directly `yourEntity.printString(...)`

Comment: still the same problem... or calll `YourClass.printString(...)`, if method is static; or `entity.printString(...)` (you need the entity to invoke its method anyway). I strongly believe the point of this question is that we do not have the Class at compile time. But never mind, just wanted to add that there is `Class.forName`

Comment: now should be ok, made some mixture during the hundreds edits :) 
Thanks

Comment: @Leviand what if the parameter for that method is none? Should I just put `null` or are there something else to put?

Comment: @Satch , in that case just use `YourClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("printString");`